# ¿Es posible "callarse" al escribir?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, sinónimos

Cuando se está en una conversación normal, es natural usar el verbo "callar" para dar a entender que no se va a decir nada más. En una conversación escrita, por ejemplo un chat en internet o en Whatsapp, ¿se puede usar este verbo para indicar que no se escribe más sobre un tema?

Ejemplo en una conversación escrita:

- No creo que debas preguntarme más sobre eso...
- Ok, ya me callo.

Algunas acepciones de [callar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6pebbaT)  en el DLE:

1. tr. Omitir o no decir algo. U. t. c. prnl.
2. intr. Dicho de una persona: No hablar, guardar silencio. Calla como un muerto. U. t. c. prnl.
3. intr. Cesar de hablar. Cuando esto hubo dicho, calló. U. t. c. prnl.

El primer significado parece poder usarse en este contexto, pero no estoy seguro. ¿Hay otro verbo más orientado al escribir?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basado en el uso corriente, la respuesta a tu pregunta es que sí, *callarse* sí puede emplearse para decir *dejar de escribir* en una conversación escrita (un chat en un sistema de mensajería como WhatsApp, por ejemplo). El sustantivo correspondiente, *silencio*, también se puede usar en este contexto, así como otras frases que en sentido estricto se refieren al discurso hablado, como *no decir más (nada)*.

El significado de *decir* hace tiempo que incluye el de *escribir* cuando se habla de comunicación (no del acto físico propiamente dicho). No es raro leer, por ejemplo, titulares como

> Clinton dice en sus memorias que tuvo que dormir en el sofá varios meses.
>
> Ricky Martin dice en su libro que sólo amó a un hombre y una mujer.

Al especificar que se trata de un escrito, no nos queda duda de que *decir* está usado en su sentido más amplio. Siendo que lo opuesto de *decir* algo es *callar*, no es extraño que el significado de este último se haya extendido también a lo escrito, por simetría.

No me consta que exista un verbo simple que cumpla con el criterio de ser a *escribir* lo que *callar* es a *hablar*.

Answer (score 2):

Hay un uso extendido de "callar" aunque sea una conversación escrita, pero he notado que se intenta esquivar esa palabra, y se usan frases más elaboradas para hacerse entender. por ejemplo: Será mejor que no opines (en caso de querer dar una opinión).

Creo sinceramente en que es mejor "no decir nada", o "no se lo digas", "no lo digas", porque decir se puede decir con la voz, las señas o las palabras.

Answer (score 1):

**Dejar, dejarlo ahí**

Tu ejemplo:

> No creo que debas preguntarme más sobre eso.
>
> Está bien, ahí lo dejo.

Otro ejemplo:

> Y ya te dije muchas veces que bla bla.
>
> Ya.  Deja con ese tema por favor.

(Más fuerte sería *¡Ya basta con ese tema!*)